# border of two divs side-by-side with `display: inline-block`

Tags: html, css

I have managed to align two `div` elements side-by-side using `display: inline-block` with the following code ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2udkrbfy/)):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     #a {
       border: 10px solid red;
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       background: black;
       font-size: 0;
     }
     #a1 {
       font-size: 16px;
       border: 10px solid green;
       width: 100px;
       height: 200px;
       background: white;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       display: inline-block;
     }
     #a2 {
       font-size: 16px;
       border:  10px solid green;
       width: 100px;
       height: 200px;
       background: white;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       display: inline-block;       
     }     
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='a'>
      <div id='apadding'>
        <div id='a1'>a1</div>
        <div id='a2'>a2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above yields the following desired result:

[image]

I can change the borders of the two `div` elements and (as long as they both have the same border) the result is the expected one.

However, when I change the border of the second `div` only, to e.g. 20 pixels this is what I get ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2udkrbfy/2/)):

[image]

Given that the `box-sizing` of both internal `div` elements is set to `border-box` I was expecting any change in the border width to be absorbed by that div's box and to not disrupt the alignment in any way. What's more puzzling is that the second `div` (whose border was changed) is the one that ends up displayed correctly while the first `div` is somehow pushed off its place.

What am I missing?

Comment: FYI: Please use jsfiddle “properly” next time - there’s no need for html & head tags, and CSS and JS should go into their respective panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the border is now included in the width the content box shrinks accordingly. That would affect the `baseline` of that div.

Since inline-block items are vertically aligned to the baseline by default, it's just a matter of setting this to `top` to solve the issue.

```css
#a {
  border: 10px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  font-size: 0;
}
#a1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 10px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
#a2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 20px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
#a1,
#a2 {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
  <div id='apadding'>
    <div id='a1'>a1</div>
    <div id='a2'>a2</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add floats!  Like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     #a {
       border: 10px solid red;
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       background: black;
       font-size: 0;
     }
     #a1 {
       font-size: 16px;
       border: 10px solid green;
       width: 100px;
       height: 200px;
       background: white;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       display: inline-block;
        float:left; <===
     }
     #a2 {
       font-size: 16px;
       border:  20px solid green;
       width: 100px;
       height: 200px;
       background: white;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       display: inline-block;   
        float:left; <===
     }     
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='a'>
      <div id='apadding'>
        <div id='a1'>a1</div>
        <div id='a2'>a2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this is a "solution" it in no way actually answers the question.

Comment: It does answer the question if you copy the code and test it out.  There are multiple answers to the question above. Your solution works as well.  Why did you ding a good answer when it addressed the problem?

Comment: As I said, it's a solution...not an answer to what is **actually being asked**.

Comment: And I stand corrected. The question was: "What am I missing?" You gotta read it again Paulie D.

Comment: What is being asked is "Why does this happen" and you haven't answered that.

Comment: Hey man, can you do a text search on this post for "Why does this happen?" and tell me where did the OP ask that question?  I stand corrected once again. Up vote me please.